# Where to insert my while loop in my code?

Tags: python, while-loop, md5

So, I have this code that I wrote and all I want it to do is to get username, password, password confirmation;
encrypt it with MD5 and save it to a file.

Now I don't understand where to insert the loop so it can tell the user when the password does not match.

Here is what I've done so far:

```
import os
import hashlib

def Main():

foods = ["username:", " \nPassword:", " \nConfpassword:"]

newU=str(raw_input("Username: "))

Password=str(raw_input("Password: "))
hash_object = hashlib.md5(Password.encode())
Password=hash_object.hexdigest()


Confpassword=str(raw_input("Password Again: "))
hash_object2 = hashlib.md5(Confpassword.encode())
Confpassword=hash_object2.hexdigest()

    if Password!=Confpassword:
    print("not match try again")
    newp=str(raw_input("again: "))
    newp=hashlib.md5(newp.encode())
    if newp.hexdigest()==hash_object.hexdigest():
        print("match")
        pass
    foods.insert(1,newU)
    foods.insert(3,hash_object.hexdigest())
    foods.insert(5,newp.hexdigest())
    with open("text.t" ,"w") as f:
            for word in foods:
                f.write(word)


else:
    pass

    #foods[0]=newf
    foods.insert(1,newU)
    foods.insert(3,hash_object.hexdigest())
    foods.insert(5,hash_object2.hexdigest())
    with open("text.t" ,"w") as f:
            for word in foods:
                f.write(word)


   if __name__ == '__main__':
           Main()
```

Comment: I've tried to edit your code's indentation but I'm not quite sure to which `if` the `else` belongs... So please do it yourself

Answer (score 0):

Cant you do:
instead of

```
 if Password!=Confpassword:
```

do this..

```
while Password!=Confpassword:
    Password=str(raw_input("Password: "))
    hash_object = hashlib.md5(Password.encode())
    Password=hash_object.hexdigest()
    Confpassword=str(raw_input("Password Again: "))
    hash_object2 = hashlib.md5(Confpassword.encode())
    Confpassword=hash_object2.hexdigest()
    #Get user to input password again
```

I know its not a complete solution but it should definitely tell you where you are going? If not please let me know and I'll flesh it out

Comment: Well, you want to read the password in in the first instance. Then you want to check if the password matches what you want.

A simplified version is something like:


`
password=raw_input()
while password!=true_password:
    password=raw_input('Please try again:')
#Do stuff here when you have the correct password `


Edit: Can someone help me with formatting please?

Comment: Can you re-post the code you've written now so we can see? I can modify it better then.